# TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having some trouble solving this error and I'm not sure where to start. This is the error:

[image: Re]

I also don't understand the second window where the arrows are pointing to the line with `<Button`.

These are the code snippets:

```
const[username, setUsername] = useState('');
```

```
<form className="app__register__login">
        <Input
          placeholder="username"
          type="text"
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
/>
```

```
{
    posts.map(({id, post}) => (
      <Post key={id} username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl}/>
    ))
}
```

When I write the following code:

```
db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
})
```

```
{
    posts.map(post) => (
      <Post username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl}/>
    ))
}
```

I don't get any error message. When I change it to this:

```
db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
    id: doc.id,
    post: doc.data(),
  }))); 
})
```

```
{
    posts.map(({id, post}) => (
      <Post key={id} username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl}/>
    ))
}
```

I get this `TypeError`.

Comment: Your code looks fine but the problem is most likely come from the `doc` itself. So you might have to try copy the data instead `{ id: doc.id, post: { ...doc.data() } }`

Comment: doesnt work either :(

Comment: If no luck, you might have to expose a model on your own like: `{ username: doc.data().username, ... }` or even with a class `new Model(doc.data())` then you cover thing in your construction

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are changing the data schema. Try this:

```
{
posts.map(({id, post}) => (
  <Post key={id} username={post.username} caption={post.post.caption} imageUrl={post.post.imageUrl}/>
))}
```

If you want to keep the consistency of your data schema, try this:

```
db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
   setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({    
        ...doc.data(),
           id: doc.id 
  }))); 
 })
```

For more info, please refer to https://medium.com/@oprearocks/what-do-the-three-dots-mean-in-javascript-bc5749439c9a

Comment: Got the same error? If yes, would you please do thos begire doing the map: console.log(snapshot.docs) see what you get

Comment: i changed my code to yours and added the console.log(snapshot.docs) but i still get the same error, nothing else apart the same error

Comment: I asked you to do so so you can check the console to see the data schema. Check it out and let me know what you got.